# How can i convert this text?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i convert this text?

From this:

```
Also known as &quot;test&quot;.
```

To this:

```
Also known as "test"
```

Comment: [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so before posting your next question here.

Comment: I would recommend using the string.replace functions

Comment: Perhaps this can help:  https://www.pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML to readable text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544284/html-to-readable-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NodeJS you can use a popular package called [entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/entities):

```
const entities = require("entities");
entities.decodeHTML("Also known as &quot;test&quot;");
// outputs: Also known as "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace function

```
'Also known as &quot;test&quot;'.replace(/&quot;/g,'');
```

The `g` flag is used with the regex to replace all the instances.