# Replace all occurrences of html tags and special unicode character from a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some text like this

```
Keeping up with friends is faster than ever.<p>&#x2022; See what friends are up to<br>&#x2022; Share updates, photos and videos<br>&#x2022;
```

And I want text like this

```
Keeping up with friends is faster than ever.
 • See what friends are up to
 • Share updates, photos and videos
```

I cleaned out html tags by `str.replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '')`, however I cannot remove special symbols.

I am calculating the length of string so special character before compiling in browser gave me different length.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's best to use an external library, like jQuery, to help you out.

In my example below, I'm using the jQuery function called text(). Here's the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/text/

As the name suggests, the jQuery text function reads the HTML as text.

```js
var asText = $("#example").text();
$("#asText").text(asText);
$("#asTextLength").text(asText.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="example">&#x2022; Ex<em>ample</em> &amp; <span>T<strong>est</strong></span></p>
<p id="asText"></p>
<p id="asTextLength"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only "right" (complete) way to do this is to parse the document in to an HTML DOM, then create something that will read the DOM and format it to your definition of "simple".

There are many tools out there to do this outside of Javascript, and prior StackOverflow exchanges discuss some of them:

- [Python convert html to text and mimic formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608555/python-convert-html-to-text-and-mimic-formatting)
- [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

I think "rolling your own" in Javascript will be painful, unless you set a VERY low bar, and only endeavor to "prettyify" a very limited amount of HTML.

That being said, why can't you just continue with the one tool you've got, and keep putting in "rules" to handle what you want to handle?

```
str.replace(/&#x2022;/gm, '•')
```

etc., etc., etc., yada yada yada, *ad nauseum*...

Comment: Or... use the jQuery suggested by Sarhanis!  (I didn't know jQuery could do that.... nifty!)

Comment: is there any way to combine all regex's replaces into one. Because I need to do :
`str = str.replace(/&#x2022;/gm, '•')` 
`str = str.replace(/ \s/g, ' ' )`
for every different possibility

Comment: @ShankarRegmi: I'm pretty sure you can string together all those `.replace()` calls: `str.replace(A,B).replace(C,D).replace(E.F)`.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-bind-html e.g.

```
<p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>

$scope.myHTML = 'Keeping up with friends is faster than ever.<p>&#x2022; See what friends are up to<br>&#x2022; Share updates, photos and videos<br>&#x2022;';
```